# Getting error with "int&"

Tags: c

I get errors VS2010 v100 Compile as C

```
(708): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'
(708): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'
(708): error C2059: syntax error : '&'
(708): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I think something wrong is with **int& b** if I change to int b - no errors but whole code works incorrect

```
void function(const int** a, int& b) /* this is 708 line */ 
{
   *code goes here...*
}

int main()
{
   ST* st = {0};
   int k;

    function(&st->value, k);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where do you define the type `ST` ? Also what should that be `ST* st = {0};` ? An initialization?

Comment: ST is structure, but it not does anything bad, something wrong with int& b

Answer (score 3):

C does not have pass-by-reference (but it should have, that would make life a lot easier for many people), you have to do it explicitly.

The code segment:

```
void xyzzy (int from, int &to) {
    to = from;
}
:
int a = 1, b = 2;
xyzzy (a, b);
```

can be re-written in C as:

```
void xyzzy (int from, int *p_to) {
    *p_to = from;
}
:
int a = 1, b = 2;
xyzzy (a, &b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass-by-reference is a C++ thing.  Either pass `b` as a pointer or pass it by value.

Comment: yes c++ I'm tring to convert to C and this int& I don't know what I shoud do

Comment: Change the parameter to `int *b` and change all occurrences of `b` in the function body to `*b`.  That should cover most simple cases, but if the function is recursively invoking itself or doing something else clever, this won't work.